# Error while trying to update Context Broker

Tags: centos, fiware, fiware-orion

I was trying to upgrade my Context Broker's version with `yum install contextBroker` but I got the following errors. Any ideas?

```
Error: Package: contextBroker-1.7.0-1.x86_64 (fiware)
           Requires: libgnutls.so.26(GNUTLS_1_4)(64bit)
Error: Package: contextBroker-1.7.0-1.x86_64 (fiware)
           Requires: libboost_regex-mt.so.5()(64bit)
Error: Package: contextBroker-1.7.0-1.x86_64 (fiware)
           Requires: libgnutls.so.26()(64bit)
```

I installed EPEL repository and I tried also with the specific rpm files but nothing fixed.

Virtualization: kvm
 Operating System: CentOS Linux 7 (Core)
 CPE OS Name: cpe:/o:centos:centos:7
 Kernel: Linux 3.10.0-327.18.2.el7.x86_64
 Architecture: x86-64

Comment: Could you update your question to include operating system and version, pls? Thx!

Answer (score 0):

The RPM availables up to now in the FIWARE yum repository (which I understand is the one you are using) work only for CentOS 6. However, it seems you are using CentOS 7.

This probably is going to change in the near future as we recently changed Orion reference distribution to CentOS 7. This allows us to generate packages for CentOS 7 starting in next Orion version to be released (1.11.0). However, not sure which policy will implement the owners of FIWARE yum repository to upload packages there (at the present moment, February 7th 2018, Orion packages in FIWARE yum repository are up to 1.7.0, i.e. missing 1.8.0, 1.9.0 and 1.10.0).

However, there are alternatives at the present moment for using Orion in CentOS 7 systems:

- Build from sources, as described [in this piece of documentation](https://fiware-orion.readthedocs.io/en/master/admin/build_source/index.html).
- Use a docker-based deployment, as described [in Dockerhub page for Orion](https://hub.docker.com/r/fiware/orion/)

Comment: I make a Centos 6 VM and i tried to install again Context Broker! Although it was fixed and i have now the version 1.7.0 of Context Broker, i cannot access it while it is running.I get a message "couldn't connect to host".Any ideas?

Comment: It seems to be a different problem. Could you open a new question about it, pls? Thx!

Comment: I finally use the docker and the problem fixed! Now i use version 1.10